# pip install issue - 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte

Tags: python, windows, encoding, utf-8, pip

As you will soon I am really new to Python, and I really need your help to understand the error I am encoutering.

I am trying to install some required package from a project ([this one](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/ml-agents)) with the command `pip install .`, and then poof:

> Building wheels for collected packages: pyyaml
>   Running setup.py
>   bdist_wheel for pyyaml ... error
>   Failed building wheel for
>   pyyaml
>   Running setup.py clean for pyyaml
>   Failed cleaning
>   build dir for pyyaml
> Failed to build pyyaml
> Installing collected
>   packages: tornado, pyzmq, jupyter-client, Send2Trash, pywinpty,
>   terminado, pickleshare, simplegeneric, parso, jedi, backcall,
>   colorama, wcwidth, prompt-toolkit, ipython, ipykernel, jinja2,
>   mistune, nbconvert, notebook, widgetsnbextension, ipywidgets,
>   jupyter-console, qtconsole, jupyter, attrs, py, pluggy,
>   more-itertools, pytest, docopt, pyyaml, unityagents
>   Running
>   setup.py install for pyyaml ... error
> Exception:
> Traceback (most
>   recent call last):
>   File
>   "C:\Users\alcid\Anaconda3\envs\ml-agents\lib\site-packages\pip\compat__init__.py",
>   line 73, in console_to_str
>     return
>   s.decode(sys.**stdout**.encoding)
> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec
>   can't decode byte 0xa0 in position 110: invalid start
>   byte
> During handling of the above exception, another exception
>   occurred:
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File
>   "C:\Users\alcid\Anaconda3\envs\ml-agents\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py",
>   line 342, in run
>     prefix=options.prefix_path,
>   File
>   "C:\Users\alcid\Anaconda3\envs\ml-agents\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py",
>   line 784, in install
>     **kwargs
>   File
>   "C:\Users\alcid\Anaconda3\envs\ml-agents\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py",
>   line 878, in install
>     spinner=spinner,
>   File
>   "C:\Users\alcid\Anaconda3\envs\ml-agents\lib\site-packages\pip\utils__init__.py",
>   line 676, in call_subprocess
>     line =
>   console_to_str(proc.stdout.readline())
>   File
>   "C:\Users\alcid\Anaconda3\envs\ml-agents\lib\site-packages\pip\compat__init__.py",
>   line 75, in console_to_str
>     return
>   s.decode('utf_8')
> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode
>   byte 0xa0 in position 110: invalid start byte
> During handling
>   of the above exception, another exception occurred:
> Traceback
>   (most recent call last):
>   File
>   "C:\Users\alcid\Anaconda3\envs\ml-agents\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py",
>   line 385, in run
>     requirement_set.cleanup_files()
>   File
>   "C:\Users\alcid\Anaconda3\envs\ml-agents\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py",
>   line 729, in cleanup_files
>     req.remove_temporary_source()
>  
>   File
>   "C:\Users\alcid\Anaconda3\envs\ml-agents\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py",
>   line 977, in remove_temporary_source
>   rmtree(self.source_dir)
>   File
>   "C:\Users\alcid\Anaconda3\envs\ml-agents\lib\site-packages\pip_vendor\retrying.py",
>   line 49, in wrapped_f
>     return Retrying(*dargs, **dkw).call(f,
>   *args, **kw)
>   File "C:\Users\alcid\Anaconda3\envs\ml-agents\lib\site-packages\pip_vendor\retrying.py",
>   line 212, in call
>     raise attempt.get()
>   File
>   "C:\Users\alcid\Anaconda3\envs\ml-agents\lib\site-packages\pip_vendor\retrying.py",
>   line 247, in get
>     six.reraise(self.value[0], self.value[1](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/ml-agents),
>   self.value[2](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/ml-agents/blob/master/docs/Installation-Windows.md))
>   File
>   "C:\Users\alcid\Anaconda3\envs\ml-agents\lib\site-packages\pip_vendor\six.py",
>   line 686, in reraise
>     raise value
>   File
>   "C:\Users\alcid\Anaconda3\envs\ml-agents\lib\site-packages\pip_vendor\retrying.py",
>   line 200, in call
>     attempt = Attempt(fn(*args, **kwargs),
>   attempt_number, False)
>   File
>   "C:\Users\alcid\Anaconda3\envs\ml-agents\lib\site-packages\pip\utils__init__.py",
>   line 102, in rmtree
>     onerror=rmtree_errorhandler)
>   File
>   "C:\Users\alcid\Anaconda3\envs\ml-agents\lib\shutil.py", line 494, in
>   rmtree
>     return _rmtree_unsafe(path, onerror)
>   File
>   "C:\Users\alcid\Anaconda3\envs\ml-agents\lib\shutil.py", line 393, in
>   _rmtree_unsafe
>     onerror(os.rmdir, path, sys.exc_info())
>   File
>   "C:\Users\alcid\Anaconda3\envs\ml-agents\lib\site-packages\pip\utils__init__.py",
>   line 114, in rmtree_errorhandler
>     func(path)
> PermissionError:
>   [WinError 32] Le processus ne peut pas accéder au fichier car ce
>   fichier est utilisé par un autre processus:
>   'C:\Users\alcid\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-kea3d7in\pyyaml'
> During
>   handling of the above exception, another exception
>   occurred:
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File
>   "C:\Users\alcid\Anaconda3\envs\ml-agents\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py",
>   line 215, in main
>     status = self.run(options, args)
>   File
>   "C:\Users\alcid\Anaconda3\envs\ml-agents\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py",
>   line 385, in run
>     requirement_set.cleanup_files()
>   File
>   "C:\Users\alcid\Anaconda3\envs\ml-agents\lib\site-packages\pip\utils\build.py",
>   line 38, in **exit**
>     self.cleanup()
>   File
>   "C:\Users\alcid\Anaconda3\envs\ml-agents\lib\site-packages\pip\utils\build.py",
>   line 42, in cleanup
>     rmtree(self.name)
>   File
>   "C:\Users\alcid\Anaconda3\envs\ml-agents\lib\site-packages\pip_vendor\retrying.py",
>   line 49, in wrapped_f
>     return Retrying(*dargs, **dkw).call(f,
>   *args, **kw)
>   File "C:\Users\alcid\Anaconda3\envs\ml-agents\lib\site-packages\pip_vendor\retrying.py",
>   line 212, in call
>     raise attempt.get()
>   File
>   "C:\Users\alcid\Anaconda3\envs\ml-agents\lib\site-packages\pip_vendor\retrying.py",
>   line 247, in get
>     six.reraise(self.value[0], self.value[1](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/ml-agents),
>   self.value[2](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/ml-agents/blob/master/docs/Installation-Windows.md))
>   File
>   "C:\Users\alcid\Anaconda3\envs\ml-agents\lib\site-packages\pip_vendor\six.py",
>   line 686, in reraise
>     raise value
>   File
>   "C:\Users\alcid\Anaconda3\envs\ml-agents\lib\site-packages\pip_vendor\retrying.py",
>   line 200, in call
>     attempt = Attempt(fn(*args, **kwargs),
>   attempt_number, False)
>   File
>   "C:\Users\alcid\Anaconda3\envs\ml-agents\lib\site-packages\pip\utils__init__.py",
>   line 102, in rmtree
>     onerror=rmtree_errorhandler)
>   File
>   "C:\Users\alcid\Anaconda3\envs\ml-agents\lib\shutil.py", line 494, in
>   rmtree
>     return _rmtree_unsafe(path, onerror)
>   File
>   "C:\Users\alcid\Anaconda3\envs\ml-agents\lib\shutil.py", line 384, in
>   _rmtree_unsafe
>     _rmtree_unsafe(fullname, onerror)
>   File "C:\Users\alcid\Anaconda3\envs\ml-agents\lib\shutil.py", line 393, in
>   _rmtree_unsafe
>     onerror(os.rmdir, path, sys.exc_info())
>   File
>   "C:\Users\alcid\Anaconda3\envs\ml-agents\lib\site-packages\pip\utils__init__.py",
>   line 114, in rmtree_errorhandler
>     func(path)
> PermissionError:
>   [WinError 32] Le processus ne peut pas accéder au fichier car ce
>   fichier est utilisé par un autre processus:
>   'C:\Users\alcid\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-kea3d7in\pyyaml'

I am really not used to python and its environment (I installed Anaconda as described in the project documentation [here](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/ml-agents/blob/master/docs/Installation-Windows.md)), and I feel like it could be really trivial for someone who knows what he is doing.

Thank you.

Comment: Try closing Anaconda (if it is open) and close cmd and try again.  You seem to have a permission error there.

Comment: Thank you sir !! I had already activate a custom environment and I suppose that was the problem. Problem solved.